# How to reliably block package version from update?

Tags: apt, dpkg, programming

I built and installed my own version of package **tora** with Oracle InstantClient support using [this guide](http://www.brainoverload.nl/general/180/install-tora-with-oracle-in-ubuntu-12-04-or-mint-13). It has the same version as the package available from standart Ubuntu repository so Synaptic tells me it needs to be updated. I blocked it there, however, apt-get does not know about it and installs the default useless version everytime I do apt-get upgrade. How can I disable such behavior? I guess I should correct the build number of my package but I don't know where to hack sources. My tora version is 2.1.3-2build1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the hold flag so that dpkg knows to ignore it. This program should do it   http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/dpkg-hold.1.html  " dpkg-hold tora" or the package name if different. Restart then check synaptic is ignoring it before updating though!

Comment: Thanks! I installed it using apt-get install dlocate. It seems working, but I'd also like to set my own version of tora package. Can you kindly explain me how to do that?

Comment: I don't have much experience but it looks like you change the number in the change log and put it back into a package.  http://wiki.debian.org/PackagingTutorial#debian.2Fcontrol